# django custom model field in admin form gives invalid choice error

Tags: django

I have the following class which to be used for a custom model field:

```
class PaymentGateway(object):

    def fullname(self):
        return self.__module__ + "." + self.__class__.__name__

    def authorize(self):
        raise NotImplemented()

    def pay(self):
        raise NotImplemented()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fullname()

class DPS(PaymentGateway):
    def authorize(self):
        pass

    def pay(self):
        pass
```

This is how I am writing the custom model field:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.six import with_metaclass
from django.utils.module_loading import import_by_path


class PaymentGatewayField(with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, models.CharField)):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 255
        super(PaymentGatewayField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value and isinstance(value, basestring):
            kls = import_by_path(value)
            return kls()
        return value

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value and not isinstance(value, basestring):
            return value.fullname()
        return value

    def value_from_object(self, obj):
        return self.get_prep_value(getattr(obj, self.attname))


    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': PaymentGatewayFormField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(PaymentGatewayField, self).formfield(**defaults)


class PaymentGatewayFormField(BaseTemporalField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in self.empty_values:
            return None
        if isinstance(value, PaymentGateway):
            return value
        if value and isinstance(value, basestring):
            kls = import_by_path(value)
            return kls()
        return super(PaymentGatewayFormField, self).to_python(value)
```

And this is how it is used in a model:

```
class BillingToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='billingtokens')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    card_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    expire_on = models.DateField()
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    payment_gateway = PaymentGatewayField(choices=[('project.contrib.paymentgateways.dps.DPS', 'DPS')])
```

I have added the model to admin:

```
class BillingTokenInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = BillingToken
    extra = 0


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BillingTokenInline]


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

So if I go to edit existing user record, which it's billingtoken record has 'DPS' already chosen, and hit save, I get a invalid choice error:

```
Select a valid choice. project.contrib.paymentgateways.dps.DPS is not one of the available choices.
```

I have tried to trace the django code and found the error message is defined in `django.forms.fields.ChoiceField`:

```
class ChoiceField(Field):
    widget = Select
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid_choice': _('Select a valid choice. %(value)s is not one of the available choices.'),
    }

    def __init__(self, choices=(), required=True, widget=None, label=None,
                 initial=None, help_text='', *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChoiceField, self).__init__(required=required, widget=widget, label=label,
                                        initial=initial, help_text=help_text, *args, **kwargs)
        self.choices = choices

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        result = super(ChoiceField, self).__deepcopy__(memo)
        result._choices = copy.deepcopy(self._choices, memo)
        return result

    def _get_choices(self):
        return self._choices

    def _set_choices(self, value):
        # Setting choices also sets the choices on the widget.
        # choices can be any iterable, but we call list() on it because
        # it will be consumed more than once.
        self._choices = self.widget.choices = list(value)

    choices = property(_get_choices, _set_choices)

    def to_python(self, value):
        "Returns a Unicode object."
        if value in self.empty_values:
            return ''
        return smart_text(value)

    def validate(self, value):
        """
        Validates that the input is in self.choices.
        """
        super(ChoiceField, self).validate(value)
        if value and not self.valid_value(value):
            raise ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['invalid_choice'],
                code='nvalid_choice',
                params={'value': value},
            )

    def valid_value(self, value):
        "Check to see if the provided value is a valid choice"
        text_value = force_text(value)
        for k, v in self.choices:
            if isinstance(v, (list, tuple)):
                # This is an optgroup, so look inside the group for options
                for k2, v2 in v:
                    if value == k2 or text_value == force_text(k2):
                        return True
            else:
                if value == k or text_value == force_text(k):
                    return True
        return False
```

But after putting some debug statements before the `raise ValidationError` line in this function, the exception is not raised here, but the error message is definitely referenced from here. Which hints me that somewhere else is extending ChoiceField might be raising this exception, and I have tried the obvious ones (ChoiceField, TypedChoiceField, MultipleChoiceField, TypedMultipleChoiceField) still no luck. This has already consumed a lot of my time and would like to seek some clever clues.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, figured out where it is throwing the error:

It's in `django/db/models/fields/__init__.py` line 236

typically because of line 234:

```
elif value == option_key:
```

Where value is a `PaymentGateway` object and option_key is a string

To fix this problem, I had to override the clean method:

```
def clean(self, value, model_instance):
    value = unicode(value) 
    self.validate(value, model_instance)
    self.run_validators(value)      
    return self.to_python(value)
```

Comment: I had the same, but it seems to me that overriding the clean (or validate) method is very lame. But seems to be the only option I guess.