# Is it possible in python to track exception raised even it has been caught?

Tags: python, django, exception

I am having a nasty bug that I simply cannot solve without having to read through the whole model form logic in django:

[django custom model field in admin form gives invalid choice error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852301/django-custom-model-field-in-admin-form-gives-invalid-choice-error)

Basically what is happening is some where in the django model form process code raised a ValidationError and then it was caught in the form process and displaying the error message.

Is it possible to track a particular type of Exception has been raised even if it has been handled inside the program?

For example:

a file within a large codebase, somewhere in this file raised an exception and also being caught, I don't know where this file is and which line...

```
1 def process_form():
2  ...logic...
3  raise ValudationError()
4  ...logic...
5  except ValudationError:
6    ...handle...
```

Some tools that shows me:
ValudationError raised in line 3

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a way, well at least it's a work around, is to go to the definition of the ValidationError and print stacktrace in the `__init__` method:

```
class ValidationError(Exception):
    """An error while validating data."""
    def __init__(self, message, code=None, params=None):
        import traceback
        print traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: An exception object being created does not necessarily mean that it is raised as well. It might as well have been created and involved in a later decision process. This doesn't happen often, but sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it can be done simply** like this:

```
 def process_form():
  ...logic...
  raise ValudationError()
  ...logic...
  except ValudationError as e:
      print e        ### 'e' will be an object of Exception raised
      import traceback
      print traceback.print_exc()
  ...handle...
```

For **multiple exceptions** like this:

```
except (ValudationError, AttributeError) as e:
```

For more info you can **read this** : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Hi thanks for trying, but my problem is I don't know where it is raising it and being caught.

Comment: Your answer assumes I know where to place `print traceback.print_exc()`, but if I know where exactly to place that line, my post is invalid.

Comment: As far as I could understand your problem, is you have a large codebase with multiple exception handlers .. Right ? But you are not sure where the exception is actually being handled. You problem can be solved if you use proper logging in the codebase, i.e. with every exception handler just provide a meaningfull log message, So that when you see the server logs you can identify the point at which the exception is being handled. Also, you can try some tools e.g. Sentry     which helps in tracking exceptions